# Size of the collection of permutations of a set in which all elements appear

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a set $A$ consisting of a finite number $N$ of elements, e.g. $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ for $N = 4$. What is the size of the collection of all possible permutations of the set $A$ into subsets such that all elements appear?  For example,

```
    {{1},{2},{3},{4}};
    {{1},{2,3,4}};
    {{2},{1,3,4}};
    {{3},{1,2,4}};
    {{4},{1,2,3}};
    {{1},{2},{3,4}};
    {{1},{3},{2,4}};
    {{1},{4},{2,3}};
    {{2},{3},{1,4}};
    {{2},{4},{1,3}};
    {{3},{4},{1,2}};
    {{1,2},{3,4}};
    {{1,3},{2,4}};
    {{1,4},{2,3}};
    {{1,2,3,4}};
```

so for $N = 4$ the size of this collection is $15$.  For $N = 3$ it is $5$, but what is it for general $N$? It seems like this must have been worked out before, but I can't quite see the pattern. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think by "permutations", you really mean "partitions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence you're describing is http://oeis.org/A000110 in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. They're called "Bell numbers", and their Wikipedia article is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number.

Both of those links contains information and references. I don't see any particularly nice formula in terms of very elementary functions, but that's probably not too surprising.

Answer (score 0):

These aren’t permutations: you’re counting the number of *partitions* of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$. The number of such partitions is the $n$-th [*Bell number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). They satisfy a nice recurrence,

$$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}kB_k\;,$$

and have a rather ugly closed form,

$$B_n=\sum_{n=0}^n\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}jj^n\;.$$

(They have a couple more rather ugly closed forms as well, as you can see at the link.) For more information and references see [their entry](http://oeis.org/A000110) in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](http://oeis.org/).